# Can logic gates be made using these components?

Tags: logic, boolean-logic

Say we have the following components:

- A wire. Transmits signal without changing it's value
- A subtractor with capacity `n`. Takes a signal from a wire, wires take `max(signal - n, 0)` from it
- A source with value `n`. Basically an input that produces `n` signal.
- A container, this is only for humans to see the result.

---

## Flow

Sources are the only way to get power, and they aren't unlimited. Once you wire a source to something, you can't wire it to something else without splitting the signal's value. Think of wires as pipes and everything else as a cup of water. The source cups are filled with `n` liters, and are tipped at the exact same time and all the water flows through the pipes. Subtractors won't let out any water unless you fill them up with `n` liters of water because the water will be inside the cup until you can fill it up enough to make the water overflow. Containers are also cups but for people to look at them and measure the water.

If you run 2 or more pipes into the same cup, the water adds up.

---

## Logic Gate Requirements

For the following requirements, `s` can be any number you want, it just must be the same for each gate.

- `NOT` Must take any signal and give out any water that is `< s` liters if there is `s` or more liters of water. Otherwise, find another source of water `>= s` and give it out. (water can't spontaneously appear)
- `AND` Must take any 2 signals and give out any amount of water `>= s` if **both** signals are `>= s`. Otherwise give out any `< s` water
- `other gates` can be made using NOT and AND, so I don't need to list them. Just make sure `s` is consistent throughout your answer

It would be great if any signals greater than `s` could be a lot greater, since there will be some randomness since it is being implemented in real life. Same for `< s` values, they should be way less.

That is not a requirement but it would be good.

Comment: Are you familiar with [fluidics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluidics)? You need an additional `AND` or `OR` component. I don't see how to create it out of the components you have at your disposal.

Comment: An OR gate is easy. @AxelKemper You just put two wires together

Comment: How will I create, for example, a `NOT` gate with an `AND` or `OR` (I can make the two, which is exactly what diode logic is capable of)

Comment: If you have NOT and OR, you get AND via `A & B = !(!A + !B)` (one of De Morgan's laws).

Comment: @AxelKemper I have `AND` and `OR` but not `NOT`

Comment: I thought you subtractor would act as inverter? `AND` and `OR` alone are not [functional complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness) to be sufficient as universal building blocks for arbitrary circuits.

Comment: @AxelKemper Which is why I am making this question to see if it is possible to create a not gate, not nessecarily out of other gates.